# Adding random font directories to use with fontspec in macOS

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Is there a way to use fonts installed in random directories in fontspec without providing the path in each use case?

e.g. I want to use the fonts installed in `~/Library/Fonts`.

So far I have only found solutions which suggest providing the path everytime a font is used.

I am looking for a global setting where a variable is set and the directory will be included in the search path for `fontspec` to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution lays up in the tree of TeX system.

It is in `kpathsea` library. Which uses `/usr/local/texlive/xxxx/texmf.cnf` to set search paths for the various types of files the system uses.

So in the above mentioned `texmf.cnf` file add the following line:

```
OSFONTDIR = /System/Library/Fonts//;/Library/Fonts//;/Users/username/Library/Fonts//
```

Where `username` is the output of the command `whoami` in Terminal.app.

You can also add other directories, if you don't want to install the fonts you use for typesetting in the regular directories.

You can look at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` for furthermore settings that might be useful to you in the future.

To test the setting you've made above run the command:

```
$ kpsewhich --expand-path '$OSFONTDIR'
```

Which would output:

```
/System/Library/Fonts:/Library/Fonts:/Users/username/Library/Fonts
```

Hope this is helpful enough.

Comment: Is the folder not in your fontconfig?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer On mac OS X, fontconfig is not used by xetex.

Comment: You can also use symlinks from inside `~/Library/Fonts` to the TeXLive locations, but this causes problems in case of updates on TeXLive side. I am not sure if your solution add some overhead to lualatex, but at any rate since a few years it should not generate doubles in its database. This looks like nice way for xelatex (I can't test here but +1)