# How do I set the TeXLive system font path for fontspec on macOS?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mactex, macos

MacTeX / TeXlive 2021 on macOS 10.15.7

I'm trying without luck to use Times New Roman via the fontspec package.

I've read that:

```
fc-list : family | sort
```

will produce a list of system fonts that I should be able to use via XeLaTeX and fontspec. This list includes Times New Roman.

This minimum test document fails

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

---

with the following log:

---

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fontspecTest.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-
01.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
No file fontspecTest.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1]
(./fontspecTest.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /Users/<user>/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman

No output PDF file written.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file fontspecTest.pdf may not be valid.
SyncTeX written on fontspecTest.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on fontspecTest.log.
```

---

I've searched on-line and read that I should edit .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf to include the font search path. I've done so, creating a file containing this, saved as /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf:

---

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf
TEXMFVAR = ~/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = ~/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-config

OSFONTDIR = System/Library/Fonts:System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental:~/Library/Fonts
```

---

However, even after running `texhash`,

```
kpsewhich --expand-path '$OSFONTDIR'
```

results in:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Fonts
```

The command:

```
fc-list : family
```

obviously searches places outside the directories specified OSFONTDIR and equally obviously my changes to texmf.cnf have had no effect.

I'd appreciate advice on how to set the appropriate search path.

Comment: I've double-checked and yes, the test document does produce that log with the load of fontenc.sty.

Comment: echo $OSFONTDIR produces null output.

Comment: The instruction to set OSFONTDIR came from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461396/adding-random-font-directories-to-use-with-fontspec-in-macos

Comment: I have in the past made various odd tweaks to my TeXLive configuration, but I stopped that long ago and I've never tweaked any of the standard distribution files, just done local configuration modifications. Any suggestions on where I might look for what's calling fontenc.sty? Thanks.

Comment: Xetex seems to find the font but then xdvipdfmx fails.  Does the document compiles with lualatex? Does the user name contain something that could confuse xdvipdfmx?

Comment: @cfr fontenc is loaded by fontspec, that is correct.

Comment: And what do you get in the log if you add \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 to the document?

Comment: It works with LuaLaTeX. Username is one alphabetic word. \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 gives no obvious change to the log file. Thanks.

Comment: \XeTeXtracingfonts should change the log (but not the terminal output).

Comment: Apologies for my mistake. I've checked the actual log files with and without  \XeTeXtracingfonts=1, using diff - only the first line shows any difference; that is, everything's the same except the time and date. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you put the command at the begin? Before the class?

Comment: Okay, fixed. diff's too long to post. Highlights:

```Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regul
ar.otf

< Requested font "Times New Roman" at 9.99997pt
<  -> /Users/rowland/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman

> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
126,127d92
< Requested font "Times New Roman/OT:language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
<  -> /Users/rowland/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman```

Comment: Hm I have no Mac but the missing extension looks odd.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry. I didn't realise it wouldn't show up in the terminal output, but only in the log.

Comment: LuaLaTeX finds the requested font at /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Times New Roman.ttf, while XeLaTeX only looks at /Users/<user>/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.

A Mac font suitcase at that path exists (file type identified by macOS file system metadata not extension) which is a wrapper around 4 font files: the m, it, b, and b+it versions of Times New Roman.

It seems that there's a search path issue affecting XeTeX but not LuaTeX. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Update: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/ contains nothing but font files with ttf, ttc, and otf extensions. I can't find the significance of the Supplemental subfolder itself, but if I could get XeTeX to search there, everything would work as well as with LuaTeX. Thanks again.